# Can you list imports from a JAR file?

Tags: reflection, import, jar

Is it possible to list the used imports from a JAR File like you can with a DLL in .NET?

I found programs that can list the content of the JAR file, like:

http://jarbrowser.sourceforge.net/

but I'd like to list the imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Jdepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html).

After compilation the import statements are no longer available,
only the types of the objects, you would need to analyze the byte code to do that.

For more details see [class file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) or even more java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/ClassFileFormat-Java5.pdf